# PostgreSQL How to cut some information from column which is a string

Tags: string, postgresql, substring

I have column File_name. With this column I need to extract 2 information:
Project and Date like integer: how can I do it in Postgresql?

```
File_name: [UFC_LOC-1001]_IGT_MISO_20191212_115w_20191213 (en-us - de-de)
```

so I need to have MISO (project (can be 3 or 4 sighs)) and next 20191212 date (int).

Comment: Is that always at the same "position" based on the `_` delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
SELECT regexp_matches('[UFC_LOC-1001]_IGT_MISO_20191212_115w_20191213 (en-us - de-de)', '([A-Z]{3,4})_([0-9]{8})');
┌─────────────────┐
│ regexp_matches  │
╞═════════════════╡
│ {MISO,20191212} │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)

SELECT r[1] as project, r[2]::date as date 
  FROM (SELECT regexp_matches('[UFC_LOC-1001]_IGT_MISO_20191212_115w_20191213 (en-us - de-de)', '([A-Z]{3,4})_([0-9]{8})') r) s;
┌─────────┬────────────┐
│ project │    date    │
╞═════════╪════════════╡
│ MISO    │ 2019-12-12 │
└─────────┴────────────┘
(1 row)
```

another variant:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(file_name, '([A-Z]{3,4})_[0-9]{8}'))[1] AS project,
       (regexp_matches(file_name, '[A-Z]{3,4}_([0-9]{8})'))[1]::date AS date 
  FROM data;
┌─────────┬────────────┐
│ project │    date    │
╞═════════╪════════════╡
│ MISO    │ 2019-12-12 │
└─────────┴────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: it is possible to have at once two column, like:
SELECT
regexp_matches(...) as project,
regexp_matches(...) as date

sth like that??
thanks!

Comment: @ElwiraSochacka - yes, it is possible, - just remove one pair of parenthesis. But it will be 2x slower

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work for (maybe I do not know how it should be) first time working with postgres, can you write me this?
And maybe will be slower but I need it :-)

Comment: and I have one more question, this column (regexp_matches) is showed like read only, ,when I try connected to view where is this column PowerBI doesnt see it :-(
It is only way to do it?

Comment: @ElwiraSochacka - I extended examples. Computed columns are read only. I don't know PowerBI, so I cannot to help. Maybe you can materialize this view to table, and this table can be visible for PowerBI - you can use statement `CREATE TABLE somename AS SELECT * FROM yourview`